# How to multiple column join in one column in excel (I Want Formula)

Tags: excel-formula

HOW TO JOIN MULTIPLE COLUMN IN ONE COLUMN

```
TABLE 1    TABLE 2     TABLE 3 
1           2            5    
2           4            3
3           5            3
4           5            1
```

I WANT TO

```
1
2
3
4
2
4
5
5
5
3
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is like below, enter the formula in the first row of any column and drag down until there is no value left over,

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:B),INDEX(B:B,ROW()-COUNTA(A:A)),IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:C),"",INDEX(C:C,ROW()-COUNTA(A:B)))))
```

[image]